# Is App Engine or Kubernetes Engine more appropriate for large, sustained workloads?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

From what I've read, one of the features of App Engine is its ability to auto scale quickly which makes it a good choice for highly variable workloads such as web traffic.

However, if I have an application that receives a consistently heavy workload (processing ~50K+ images per day) would it be more appropriate to use a Kubernetes Engine cluster? I want to reduce as much maintenance time as possible i.e. just deploy it and forget about it.

The application isn't very containerized in that it's not using some sort of modular micro services architecture and some things I've read said that Kubernetes Engine would be overkill if that's the case. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to deploy your app and forget about it, you definitely should go for App Engine, over K8s.

Depending on your needs, you would go for Standard or Flex. With Flex, you still need to containerize your app in a Docker image.

K8s needs more attention. You need to have a clear picture of your application architecture, which includes security, networking, etc, and build it by pieces.

With App Engine you forget about lots of these blocks, and focus more in the app itself.

In my opinion, K8s would not be overkilling. Both are appropriate for your app.